# Ansible user module not idempotent when using groups argument

Tags: ansible

I encounter that ansible task and ad-hoc command always change when using `user` module together with argument `groups`.

*ansible --version*

```
ansible 2.8.5
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.16 (default, Dec 12 2019, 23:58:22) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
```

Example ad-hoc

```
ansible -c local -i localhost, -m user -a "uid=10001 name=foobar group=person home=/home/foobar state=present groups=person" all
```

Example *playbook* task

```
- name: ensure users are present
  become: true
  user:
    uid: 10001
    name: foobar
    group: person
    groups:
      - person
    home: /home/foobar
    state: present
```

If I delete the *groups* property the tasks doesn't change all the time.

Thank you

Comment: Do you define a password or shell for the user or anything isn't mentioned in your task?

Comment: No, but for me this isn't an issue anymore. I am not having this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your claim, but I noticed you add the user to the group `person` twice (why?). The `group` parameter is for the primary group, this ensures field 4 in /etc/passwd matches gid. The `groups` parameter is for secondary groups, it adds foobar to groups in /etc/group. L